# how to replace : in grep output +

Tags: linux, command-line, grep, tooltip

if you do grep -n, the output format is like this,

filename:line:

Is it possible for me to tell grep to replace the first : with + so that I can copy paste the string to vim to go to that line?

What I want is this,

filename +line:

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: What's the difference between `filename:line:`and `filename+line:`?what do you really want to achieve? Some automatic tasks? Or just to view those files with vim and go to that line quickly?

Comment: Yes. Just to copy the entire content in one shot and give it to vim. To save some time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pipe the output to `sed`.

```
grep -n needle haystack1 haystack2  | sed 's/:/ +/'
```

If you then want to strip off the part after, so that it is even easier to paste to vim, you can pipe it to awk.

```
grep -n needle haystack1 haystack2  | sed 's/:/ +/' | awk -F':' '{print $1}'
```